# Suggested date & time pickers for ExactTarget Landing Pages using AMPscript?

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, datetime, ampscript, calendar

We're trying to determine an easy and usable solution to allow our administrators to have a date & time selector (almost certainly jquery or javascript based) available for forms built in ExactTarget Landing Pages using AMPscript to edit rows ina  data extension. I had a solid experience with the jqueryui datepicker component but it doesn't handle time of day and the next development stage requires that Time is handled within the DateTime parameter. So far a limited web search suggests I'll need to use several to see which works well. If anyone has done this before and has this experience you can probably save a lot of people a lot of time by sharing. I hope this helps others as well as myself and if I do need to self-research it I promise to come back and share the results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are a few options, however there isn't any specific library we would recommend for this.

A couple options for you would be:

- https://github.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker
- http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/
- https://github.com/perifer/timePicker
- http://www.ama3.com/anytime/
- http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

You can also do this with a simple drop down as well.

Comment: interesting, had not considered a simple drop down for that though that would be a low profile solution. I know I need to work out some of the logic of multiple input fields supplying and decoding the two isolated aspects of datetime. That sounds like a job for DatePart doesn't it?